# JRadioButton and component changes

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, jradiobutton

I created a JDialog box where it has 2 radio button which will change the JLabel whenever I clicked the other button(for example: Monthly salary when I click the full time button and hourly pay when i click the part time button)

So my questions is how do i do that? Do I create ActionListener  for the radioButton and create the those JPanel inside the the actionPerformed class?

[image: example]

Comment: Which part you're missing ? The JDialog or the action ?

Comment: sorry the action part not the JDialog

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to go about this is create an action listener for the button. When one is selected change the text with `monthLabel.setText("Monthly Salary");`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need listener, I recommend `ItemListener` over `ActionListener` but there is no need to create Panel in listener. Instead change the label text itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it:

```
radio1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   label.setText("Clicked from radio 1");
});

radio2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   label.setText("Clicked from radio 2");
});
```